# Colorbox Not working in IE showing invalid argument in jquery.js

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using the colorbox on my site. It is working fine on chrome and firefox in IE it is just faded the background color not showing the popup. The developers tool showing the following errors.
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 8826
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I have solved it by the include both colorbox jquery file(colorbox.js and colorbox.min.js).I was due to the jquery file.I was using only one jquery file(colorbox.js).

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer does not like to play nice with cool plugins. What I usually do is force ie into comp compatibility mode so that it acts like ie7,then target it to see if the problem is still appearing.

Try the following code below to your html file and see if that fixes the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

**Also Make sure to include both jquery files for the plugin you are using**

Comment: not working showing the same.It is fading the background only not the pop up

Comment: I have solved it by the include both colorbox jquery file(colorbox.js and colorbox.min.js).I was due to the jquery file.I was using only one jquery file(colorbox.js).

Comment: Good to hear can you choose my answer as final answer since your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to be able to answer your question.  I expect you have some sort issue with your syntax.  Try showing us the contents of your $(document).ready callback.